# why does my var returns NaN instead of an html structure?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, innerhtml

Im trying to get my var to show me an html structure but it shows NaN
why?

I tried a lot of things like console.log(rankinU) and it works. somehow html2 doesnt

```
var i = 0;
var html2 = '';
const listaRanking = document.querySelector('#lista');
db.collection("usuarios").orderBy("puntos", "desc").limit(10)
    .get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            data                = doc.data();

            const rankinU  = `
        <div class="containerFlex">
            <div class="rank">#${i+1}</div>
            <div class="usuario">${data.usuario}</div>
            <div class="puntosr">${data.puntos}</div>
        </div>
        `;
            html2 =+ rankinU;

            console.log(html2);
            listaRanking.innerHTML = html2;
            i++;
    });
});
```

I expect it to show anything but a Nan

Comment: Because you're setting it to an attempt to convert an HTML string into a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html2 =+ rankinU;` should be `html2 += rankinU;`.

- `a += b` translates to `a = a + b`, which is valid for strings.
- `a =+ b` translates to `a = +b`, which is not valid for strings, it will then assume `b` is a number and try to parse it as a number (which it is not, hence `NaN` when assigned to `a`).

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
html2 =+ rankinU;
```

You're trying to use the compound assignment operator, which is `+=`. Your above code is equivalent to:

```
html2 = +rankinU;
```

And the unary `+` operator attempts to convert its argument to a number. This can't happen with that HTML string, so you're getting `NaN`. Just change the operator out:

```
html2 += rankinU;
```

Or use the verbose notation - either way works:

```
html2 = html2 + rankinU;
```

Comment: ohhh thanks. jajaja that was funny. Ive been wokking on this for over 8 hs and im all rusty now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem @JoaquinROMERO, always glad to help.